# bbox not restrict search results

Tags: here-api

I'm reviewing HERE API, and I can't figure this issue:
I'm interesting in `Geocoder` API, and I tried the following query:

`http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?
&app_id=***
&app_code=***
&searchtext=london
&bbox=41.9085286,-87.6762943;41.8682739,-87.6041965
&gen=8`

The bonding box I defined is around Chicago USA, so I expect to get no results.
But the response contains London information and I cant figure why.

I read [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600367/why-are-search-results-not-limited-to-the-bounding-box) that If I use the `landmark` request the `bbox` is not always taken into consideration.
But here i'm using `geocode` requirest.

Answer (score 0):

The geocoder does include prominent results (like London in this case) in the response in case of bbox, maybe you can use country as an additional filter  ?